# IPv6 forwarding enabled but not working. How to get it to work?

Tags: ipv6, ip-forwarding, systemd-networkd

My system is running Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
My network is configured with two interfaces, one to my ISP and one to my lan.
I am using systemd-networkd to manage the interfaces. The problem is IPv6 is not being forwarded. (systemd version 247.3-6 )

I can ping -6 my upstream from the router but not from an internal host. Internal hosts are unable to connect to external IPv6 servers but can connect to external IPv4 servers via a NAT connection.

```
cat /etc/systemd/network/eth0.network
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
IPv6AcceptRA=yes
IPForward=ipv6
LLDP=yes

[DHCPv6]
PrefixDelegationHint=::/56

cat /etc/systemd/network/lan0.network 
[Match]
Name=lan0

[Network]
Address=192.168.1.2/24
Address=192.168.1.1/24
Address=192.168.1.5/24
Address=192.0.2.5/24
Address=2001:0DB8:c101:b700::1/64
Address=2001:0DB8:c101:b700:beef::5/64

Domains=lan example.com

IPForward=ipv6
LLDP=yes

ip -6 route show table all
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:0DB8:c101:b700::/64 dev lan0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev lan0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::2a2:ff:feb2:c2 dev eth0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1724sec mtu 1500 pref high
local ::1 dev lo table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local 2001:0DB8:c000:1b7:f3d4:d970:ca28:bf4f dev eth0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
anycast 2001:0DB8:c101:b700:: dev lan0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local 2001:0DB8:c101:b700::1 dev lan0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local 2001:0DB8:c101:b700:beef::5 dev lan0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
anycast fe80:: dev eth0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
anycast fe80:: dev lan0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::fca5:6fff:fe75:6109 dev eth0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::fca5:6fff:fe75:6129 dev lan0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev eth0 table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev lan0 table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium

ip a
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether fe:a5:6f:75:61:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 192.0.2.199/23 brd 192.0.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
           valid_lft 1602sec preferred_lft 1602sec
        inet6 2001:0DB8:c000:1b7:f3d4:d970:ca28:bf4f/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
           valid_lft 3802sec preferred_lft 2802sec
        inet6 fe80::fca5:6fff:fe75:6109/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    3: lan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether fe:a5:6f:75:61:29 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 192.0.2.5/24 brd 192.0.2.255 scope global lan0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global lan0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet 192.168.1.5/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary lan0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 2001:0DB8:c101:b700:beef::5/64 scope global 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 2001:0DB8:c101:b700::1/64 scope global 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::fca5:6fff:fe75:6129/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

ip6tables-save
# Generated by ip6tables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Mar 27 06:29:25 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [127035:902105282]
:client_in - [0:0]
:client_out - [0:0]
:nameserver_in - [0:0]
:server_in - [0:0]
:server_out - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m rt --rt-type 0 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lan0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s fe80::/10 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d ff00::/8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 2001:0DB8:c101:b700::1/128 -i eth0 -j nameserver_in
-A INPUT -d 2001:0DB8:c101:b700::5/128 -i eth0 -j nameserver_in
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m rt --rt-type 0 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 2001:0DB8:c101:b700::/56 -i lan0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 2001:0DB8:c101:b700:beef::/80 -i eth0 -j server_in
-A FORWARD -d 2001:0DB8:c101:b700::/125 -i eth0 -j nameserver_in
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -m rt --rt-type 0 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s fe80::/10 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d ff00::/8 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
-A client_in -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A client_out -j ACCEPT
-A nameserver_in -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A nameserver_in -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A server_in -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A server_in -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A server_in -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A server_in -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A server_out -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Mar 27 06:29:25 2022

networkctl status lan0
● 3: lan0                                                                      
                     Link File: /lib/systemd/network/73-usb-net-by-mac.link
                  Network File: /etc/systemd/network/lan0.network
                          Type: ether
                         State: routable (configured)
                          Path: platform-xhci-hcd.0.auto-usb-0:1:1.0
                        Driver: r8152
                        Vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
                         Model: RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
                    HW Address: fe:a5:6f:75:61:29
                           MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 9194)
                         QDisc: pfifo_fast
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: eui64
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 1/1
              Auto negotiation: yes
                         Speed: 1Gbps
                        Duplex: full
                          Port: mii
                       Address: 192.168.1.1
                                192.168.1.5
                                192.0.2.5
                                2001:0DB8:c101:b700::1
                                2001:0DB8:c101:b700:beef::5
                                fe80::fca5:6fff:fe75:6129
                Search Domains: lan
                                example.com

Mar 27 05:35:20 firewall systemd-networkd[6691]: lan0: Gained IPv6LL
Mar 27 05:44:47 firewall systemd-networkd[6750]: lan0: Gained IPv6LL
Mar 27 06:19:05 firewall systemd-networkd[7041]: lan0: Gained IPv6LL

networkctl status eth0
● 2: eth0                                                                      
                     Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
                  Network File: /etc/systemd/network/eth0.network
                          Type: ether
                         State: routable (configured)
                          Path: platform-ff540000.ethernet
                    HW Address: fe:a5:6f:75:61:09
                           MTU: 1500 (min: 46, max: 3712)
                         QDisc: mq
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: eui64
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 8/8
              Auto negotiation: yes
                         Speed: 1Gbps
                        Duplex: full
                          Port: tp
                       Address: 192.0.2.199 (DHCP4 via 202.90.244.1)
                                2001:0DB8:c000:1b7:f3d4:d970:ca28:bf4f
                                fe80::fca5:6fff:fe75:6109
                       Gateway: 202.90.244.1
                                fe80::2a2:ff:feb2:c2
                           DNS: 202.142.142.142
                                202.142.142.242
                                2001:0DB8:100:1::142
                                2001:0DB8:1:5::242
               DHCP4 Client ID: IAID:0xa3d03369/DUID
             DHCP6 Client IAID: 0xa3d03369
             DHCP6 Client DUID: DUID-EN/Vendor:0000ab111f00fd4412b87eae0000

Mar 27 05:44:47 firewall systemd-networkd[6691]: eth0: DHCPv6 lease lost
Mar 27 05:44:47 firewall systemd-networkd[6750]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Mar 27 05:44:50 firewall systemd-networkd[6750]: eth0: DHCPv4 address 192.0.2.199/23 via 202.90.244.1
Mar 27 05:44:51 firewall systemd-networkd[6750]: eth0: DHCPv6 address 2001:0DB8:c000:1b7:f3d4:d970:ca28:bf4f/128 timeout preferred 3000 valid 4000
Mar 27 06:00:17 firewall systemd-networkd[6750]: eth0: DHCPv6 address 2001:0DB8:c000:1b7:f3d4:d970:ca28:bf4f/128 timeout preferred 3000 valid 4000
Mar 27 06:15:52 firewall systemd-networkd[6750]: eth0: DHCPv6 address 2001:0DB8:c000:1b7:f3d4:d970:ca28:bf4f/128 timeout preferred 3000 valid 4000
Mar 27 06:19:04 firewall systemd-networkd[6750]: eth0: DHCPv6 lease lost
Mar 27 06:19:05 firewall systemd-networkd[7041]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Mar 27 06:19:07 firewall systemd-networkd[7041]: eth0: DHCPv6 address 2001:0DB8:c000:1b7:f3d4:d970:ca28:bf4f/128 timeout preferred 3000 valid 4000
Mar 27 06:19:08 firewall systemd-networkd[7041]: eth0: DHCPv4 address 192.0.2.199/23 via 202.90.244

sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

Comment: (The system should allow 546/UDP for DHCPv6 to not timeout I guess.) Is there a setting to apply somewhere for your upstream router to know about `2001:0DB8:c101:b700::/64`?

Comment: The networkctl status eth0 statement indicates DHCP is working as IPv4 and IPv6 addresses are released at Mar 27 06:19:04 and re-assigned at Mar 27 06:19:07  (NB addresses have been obfusticated)